# Debugging with valgrind and gdb

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, valgrind

Good afternoon! This is my first post here!

I have an invalid write error when I use valgrind, but when I can figure it when I use gdb!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define MAX_INDEX 2

 void *z_m = 0;
 struct block {
    struct block * suiv;
 };

 //Declaration of a global array 
 struct block * tzl[MAX_INDEX+1];

 //Function used to dislay tzl in the main.
 void display() {
    for(int i=0; i<=MAX_INDEX; i++) {
        struct bloc * tmp = tzl[i];
        printf("%d  =>  ",i);
        while (tmp!=NULL) {
            printf(" %li  ->",(unsigned long)tmp);
            tmp = tmp -> suiv;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }

 int main() {
    z_m = (void *) malloc(1<<MAX_INDEX);
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_INDEX; i++) 
    {
         tzl[i] = NULL;
    }
    tzl[MAX_INDEX] = z_m;
    //Here is the problem with valgrind
    tzl[MAX_INDEX] -> suiv = NULL;
    display();
    free(z_m);
    return 0;
}
```

What can be the problem? Thank you for answering.

Comment: Can you please explain (or rephrase) the statement "but when I can figure it when I use gdb"?

Comment: BTW, your symbol (functions and variables) names are practically unreadable (at least for the common English reader, which is the how questions are expected to be posted here).

Comment: I'm sorry! I tried to add some comments. When I use gdb, the process is terminating normally which is strange for me considering the error in valgrind!

Comment: [Tank you](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvtqhj5antDCN6_jmlieKVfse2nLD_HsQRRBAe1xRNVUqXjQA)!?! ;-)

Comment: @Cool Guy: It is just a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `tzl[2]` with a pointer to a block of 4 bytes:

```
tzl[MAX_INDEX] = z_m;    /* z_m is malloc(4) */
```

But you are then treating it as a pointer to `struct block`:

```
tzl[MAX_INDEX] -> suiv = NULL;
```

Declare `z_m` as `struct block *` and change `malloc(1<<MAX_INDEX)` to `malloc(sizeof(struct block))` for a start.

You should also check to make sure `malloc` did not return NULL, and you should probably refrain from casting `malloc`'s return value.

Comment: Ok! Thank you dear, it helps in some way!
But, you know why gdb can figure out the error?

Comment: gdb does not check that you don't misuse memory.  The misuse here is slight, and you're likely to "get away with it" (that is, the code is likely to seem to run correctly, even though it has a problem).  valgrind checks much more carefully.  It's good that valgrind found the problem for you.